# Android Динамическое изменение темы в runtime

Tags: android, kotlin

Хочу реализовать изменение темы с поддержкой старых устройств (вплоть до 4.0).

В поисках информации я наткнулся на [статью](https://proandroiddev.com/change-theme-dynamically-with-circular-reveal-animation-on-android-8cd574f5f0d8).

**Но начнем сначала.**
Сейчас экран выглядит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого используются

**Style**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

**и Style для кнопки**

```
<style name="Login.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/color_primary</item>
</style>
```

**MainActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        binding = AcMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        initViews()
}
```

Мне нужно сохранить вид этой кнопки.

**Изменение темы**

**ButtonTheme**

```
data class ButtonTheme (
    @ColorRes
    val textColor: Int,
    @ColorRes
    val color: Int
)
```

**MyButton**

```
class MyButton
@JvmOverloads
constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), ThemeManager.ThemeChangedListener {

    override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()
        ThemeManager.addListener(this)
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        ThemeManager.addListener(this)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
        ThemeManager.removeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onThemeChanged(theme: Theme) {
        setTextColor(
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, theme.buttonTheme.textColor)
        )
        setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, theme.buttonTheme.color)
        )
    }
}
```

**Theme**

```
enum class Theme(
    val buttonTheme: ButtonTheme
){
    DARK(
        buttonTheme = ButtonTheme(
            color = R.color.color_primary,
            textColor = android.R.color.white
        )

    ),

    LIGHT(
        buttonTheme = ButtonTheme(
            color = R.color.color_primary_dark,
            textColor = android.R.color.black
        )
    )
}
```

**ThemeManager**

```
object ThemeManager {
    private val listeners = mutableSetOf<ThemeChangedListener>()

    var theme = Theme.LIGHT
        set(value) {
            field = value
            listeners.forEach{ listener -> listener.onThemeChanged(value) }
        }



    fun addListener(listener: ThemeChangedListener){
        listeners.add(listener)
    }

    fun removeListener(listener: ThemeChangedListener){
        listeners.remove(listener)
    }


    interface ThemeChangedListener{
        fun onThemeChanged(theme: Theme)
    }
}
```

**LayoutInflater**

```
class MyLayoutInflater(
    private val delegate: AppCompatDelegate
) : LayoutInflater.Factory2{

    override fun onCreateView(parent: View?, name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
        return when(name){
            "Button" -> MyButton(context, attrs, R.attr.buttonStyle)
//            "Button" -> Button(context, attrs, R.attr.buttonStyle)
            else -> delegate.createView(parent, name, context, attrs)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
        return onCreateView(null, name, context, attrs)
    }
}
```

Применяю Inflater

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory2(
            LayoutInflater.from(this),
            MyLayoutInflater(delegate)
        )
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        binding = AcMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        initViews()

    }
```

После всех манипуляций:

1. После открытия Fragment.
2. Первое нажатие на смену темы
3. Второе нажатие на смену темы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как теперь привязать мой style кнопки к ним?

Я пробовал и так

```
"Button" -> MyButton(context, attrs, R.style.Login_Button)
```

Но там получались просто узкие полоски 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал и в MyButton воткнуть, но там вообще нету метода для установки style.

Comment: <item name="strokeColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>

Comment: @Circassian а при чем тут цвет? Я цвет и через Theme могу установить. Я написал что не могу style установить, присущим кнопкам в material design (circle animation при нажатии). Там и кнопки становятся закругленными и меньше они по размерам

Comment: @krossovochkin не поможете с ответом?